# How do I align the text and accompanied image horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Here is the result of the code below:

[image]

If I make the first image bigger then I have this one (The text goes far below the image) :

[image]

Now the question is:

**How do I align each text and image horizontally?** 
(I want the text on the middle of the image not on the lower edge)

```html
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/32x30' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:32px; height:30px;'>
<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'>
<b>Diamonds: {valueY.value}</b>
</span><br>
<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/32x30' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:32px; height:30px;'>
<span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Performance: {Performance}</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Convert the image `vertical-align` property from `bottom` to `top`.
It's better to divide your structure into divs that will make controlling of elements designs much easier.

Comment: Changing vertical-align property from bottom to middle solved the problem... Why I didn't noticed that :)

Comment: Could you please give me a hint on how to divide my structure into divs ...

Comment: You should throw your two lines of text into a single div(think of it like a box).  That way the whole box will be moved where it needs to and the text inside will always be aligned in the same spot.

Comment: And throw your two images in a single box(div) too.

Comment: @dmikester1
What you said will be fine if we want to move the images independent of the text, but I think in SaraRee case we need to move each image with its corresponding text.
a structure like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A7mL9mzNuGjD4W-GllcAhcFgQ5D_6CWf/view?usp=sharing) may be fine.
we have 2 `divs` one hold the image and the other one holds the text each of them is part of a parent `div`. now we can move them together and if we want to style them in another way we can do that inside the parent `div`.
Please do not be afraid of asking for more clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

To make the text horizontally centered comparing to the images you can make it's position absolutely & push it 50% from top and push it back of it's own height. So it will be vertically centered comparing to the left image/icon. Here is what I mean:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'>
  <span>
    <b>Diamonds: {valueY.value}</b>
  </span><br>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/300/?blur'>
  <span>
    <b>Performance: {Performance}</b>
  </span>
</div>
```

I have wrapped each block within a div element so I can make the div position relatively.

Here is the css:

```
.wrapper { position: relative; }
img {
  vertical-align: bottom; margin-right: 10px; 
  width:32px; height:30px;
}
span {
  font-size:14px; color:#000000; display: inline-block; 
  position: absolute; 
/*  push it by 50% from top  */
  top: 50%;
/*  push it back of it's own height  */
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[Here is the live preview](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/eXyRwJ)